# first "non-replaceable" parts to break

Tags: engine, maintenance, body-work

I'm currently modifying my '08 Subaru WRX with everything from suspension(Sways/Strut/Springs...) to Engine(Turbo/TMIC/Injectors...) and much much more...However I would like to get ahead of the game when it comes to major setbacks that could happen as the car ages.

What parts of the vehicle are generally first to go due to old age, that do not have a direct replacement part?  For example a busted Radiator is as easy as sliding a new aftermarket one in, but a hole in the floor due to rust will require custom welding and so on.

I would like to identify the areas of the vehicle that will require this type of custom work down the road and if anyone can enlighten me on an issue that has absolutely no fix it would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: For the vote to close folks. I don't think this question is too broad (IMO), the OP is basically asking about pattern failures for this car. Someone very familiar with these cars, a Subaru dealership technician for example would be able to write a great detailed answer to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know from experience that the doors like to rust after about 7 years if you're not careful. I don't know of anything else except the usual problems like cracking radiators, blown headgaskets and broken main bearings (usually under #3 piston). Other things that go wrong include the main oil seal and the clutch. If you have a VF39 STI turbo, it might crack on the turbine side at some point. But these things aren't really what you were asking about.

That's all I can think of.

Source: I have a 2007 Forester XT, which is basically a WRX on stilts.

Comment: I was just telling the "they used to be tall WRXes" story, bemoaning how silly Foresters have become.

Comment: @Juann I appreciate the detailed feedback, the driver behind my question is from an observation I made when doing the first oil change after purchasing used at 100k km.  I took the plastic undercover off and the front cross member is severely rusted...I'm unsure whether a new one can be welded in without affecting the frame...

Comment: I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Juann - good car choice! Mine's the Litchfield Forester STi (currently a 400bhp Impreza on slightly shorter stilts). Additional rust area - arches will go not long after doors

Comment: Tip: remove all rust, then apply Rustoleum or some other rust-inhibiting coating.

Comment: @JuannStrauss For rust treatment and prevention you can't beat [POR15](http://www.por15.com/SUPER-STARTER-KIT--Black_p_11.html) I don't have any affiliation with them, they are just the best I have ever seen at rust treatment.

Comment: Oh, and you don't even have to remove the rust, it is designed to go right on top of it.